# Semantic web language bases

Tags: java, scala, semantic-web

I'm starting a semantic web project and [judging from this overview](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/Java), most of the tools for constructing semantic webs are made for Java. I would loath having to use Java, so my question is: how easily can I expect it to be to utilize these tools from Scala? Will there be compatibility problems?

Comment: Did you give it a try? I guess no one can provide a good answer to that. In general, you can use all Java APIs from within Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with pretty much every Java API you probably would want to create a thin wrapper which:

- converts Java Collections and Arrays to the Scala equivalents
- converts stuff that might be null to Options
- fixes the broken generics of Java

But there shouldn't be any serious problems.